# In VBA, how do I sequentially add an image to each slide?

Tags: image, vba, loops, powerpoint

I need to add a sequence of images numbered from 0 - 1400 in steps of 56 (0, 56, 112, etc) to each slide in a presentation and then make the background transparent

So far I have:

```
Sub InsertImage()

ActiveWindow.Selection.SlideRange.Shapes.AddPicture( _
 FileName:="C:\Folder\Image0.bmp", _
 LinkToFile:=msoFalse, _
 SaveWithDocument:=msoTrue, Left:=25, Top:=90, _
 Width:=265, Height:=398.5).Select

End Sub

Sub MakeTransparent()

  With ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange
     .PictureFormat.TransparentBackground = msoTrue
     .PictureFormat.TransparencyColor = RGB(41, 41, 241)
     .Fill.Visible = msoFalse
  End With

End Sub
```

Which will do each one individually, but this is no faster than doing them one by one?

Any help is much appreciated!

Thanks,

Lauren

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you want to start at Slide 1 and that you've already got enough slides in the presentation to contain all the images, try something like this (total air-code):

```
Sub InsertImages()

Dim lImageNumber as Long
Dim lSlideNumber as Long 
Dim oSh as Shape

lSlideNumber = 1  ' Slide counter

For lImageNumber = 0 to 1400 Step 56
   Set oSh = ActivePresentation.Slides(lSlideNumber).Shapes.AddPicture( _
     FileName:="C:\Folder\Image" & cstr(lImageNumber) & ".bmp", _
     LinkToFile:=msoFalse, _
     SaveWithDocument:=msoTrue, Left:=25, Top:=90, _
     Width:=265, Height:=398.5)

     lSlideNumber = lSlideNumber + 1

    With oSh
     .PictureFormat.TransparentBackground = msoTrue
     .PictureFormat.TransparencyColor = RGB(41, 41, 241)
     .Fill.Visible = msoFalse
    End With

Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Ah that's brilliant.  I've never used VBA before so it's nice to have a concise answer that works. Thanks :-)

Comment: Great ... glad to have been able to help.  Extra points back to you for stating your problem clearly and showing the code you had tried to date.  Makes our job so much easier. ;-)